# How to pause code execution for non-modal window(Form.show())

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

Currently, I have a vb.net report application that calls another DLL (C#) method that has `Form.ShowDialog()` to opens an embedded browser window. When the embedded browser window closes, it sends a message to database and we update the main report application based on the message.

Now we wanted to make the embedded browser window modeless by using `Form.Show()`. The goal here is to allow users view the main application while working on the embedded browser window, but we are going to disable some functionalities in the main application and re-enable them at the end.

I tried to send message in the `FormClosedEventHandler` in the C# project, but it's not really ideal. Looks like I have to refactor a lot code to move the code into the form closed event. Even I go this route, seems there is no easy way for main application to know when the embedded browser windows is closed and re-enable the functionalities that are disabled early.

Are there any ways to pause the code execution like ShowDialog() or any suggestions?

Comment: There is an easy way. The first form handles the FormClosed event of the second form. It works exactly the same way as for a child control. Whatever you would previously have had after ShowDialog goes in that event handler.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you simply handle the dialogue's `FormClosed` event exactly as you would a child control. In VB, you could declare a field `WithEvents` and use a `Handles` clause, just as is done with controls added in the designer:

```vb
Private WithEvents someDialogue As SomeForm

Private Sub someDialogue_FormClosed(...) Handles someDialogue_FormClosed
    'The dialogue has closed so do as appropriate here.

    'Clear the field to remove the event handler, if and only if the same form will not be used again.
    someDialogue = Nothing
End Sub
```

Otherwise, you can register the event handler explicitly when you create the object and remove it when you're done:

```vb
Private Sub someDialogue_FormClosed(...)
    'The dialogue has closed so do as appropriate here.

    Dim dialogue = DirectCast(sender, SomeForm)

    RemoveHandler dialogue.FormClosed, AddressOf someDialogue_FormClosed
End Sub
```

```vb
Dim dialogue As New SomeForm

AddHandler dialogue.FormClosed, AddressOf someDialogue_FormClosed
```

Comment: Sorry,  I think my poor description of the issue might not described my issue correctly here. My main report application didn't call to open the form from C# project. It calls a adapter project to do some validations(I left this part out  to try to make it simpler), and then the adapter calls a method from the c# project that has someform.show(). How can I detect the C# project's someform from the main report application? Sorry for the confusion!